# Applying css stylesheet to a specific site/page in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, aspx

I have made a custom search portal for a sharepoint library. As instructed in a different topic here I have selected the stylesheet in the Settings of this site. But it seems this also applies to all top-level sites and document-library views.
How do I apply a stylesheet to a single site?

Comment: I assume you are using the alternateCssUrl property and classic sites. Just reference the css in the page using a content editor or script editor web part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a Content Editor WebPart on te page with a LINK to a CSS file.

If it's not a WebPart page you have to go the more technical route:

Use JavaScript, which adds a LINK element to `document.head` in the MasterPage itself; but you need to check the URL for execution on the correct page

More technical is a **Web** Scoped UserCustomAction, a JavaScript file which only executes on the Web (and not its SubWebs)
Easy to attach using the SPEditor Chrome Extension:

- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sp-editor/ecblfcmjnbbgaojblcpmjoamegpbodhd?hl=en

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggesting that extension, will definitely check that out.